# PDF empty in Android when using Expo and React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I receive a pdf in base64 form. I'm trying to implement a share button to share the pdf in React Native/Expo.

I have tried several things to no success. Now I have this that works on ios but not on Android, the pdf is empty.

Why?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import * as Print from 'expo-print';

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onShare = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const html = `<html>
      <head>
        <title>Embedded PDF</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <embed
          src="data:application/pdf;base64,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"
          width="100%"
          height="600px"
          type="application/pdf"
        />
      </body>
    </html>`;

    const localUri = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html });
    await Sharing.shareAsync(localUri.uri).catch((err) => console.log('Sharing::error', err));
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <View >
      {loading && <ActivityIndicator />}
      <Text onPress={onShare}>
        Share
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Check if your device has enough memory to render the PDF. If not, you can try to optimize the PDF file size by reducing the resolution or compressing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Android doesn't come with a PDF Viewer for browsers. iOS does.

You can make the user download the PDF, so he can open it with the app of his choice, or include PDF.js in your HTML (via  CDN).